# Are .manifest files only for managed .NET assemblies?

Tags: .net

Are .manifest files only for managed .NET assemblies? Or can they be used for native code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manifests are part of what a .NET assembly is.

There is no direct equivalent in native code (all the type metadata for instance is not something that has been defined for native code).

From [Manifest (CLI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_%28CLI%29) on Wikipedia:

> An assembly manifest is a text file containing metadata about CLI assemblies. It describes the relationship and dependencies of the components in the assembly, versioning information, scope information and the security permissions required by the assembly.